# PHP included functions not working in firefox 5

Tags: php, function, include, call

I have 2 files:

create.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
require("Test.php");
hello();
echo "does this work?";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and Test.php:

```
<?php
function hello(){
    echo "hello";
}
?>
```

But when I open create.php, nothing prints (not even "does this work?". If I call hello() from Test.php it works fine. That is, it doesn't seem to be executing code after the include. What am I doing wrong?

edit: the code seems to work fine in my IE 8 install, but not in my FF 5 install (which, admittedly, has way to many addons).

edit again: the issue was that the page cache needed to be refreshed. There was never a problem. The code works. sorry, all.

Comment: Test.php, if it is to be included, should not have all the HTML you have in there; it's duplicated in the caller.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the problem. Personally, I think it's a path issue so maybe mention something about that?

Comment: Is `test.php` in the same directory as `create.php`?

Comment: I removed the HTML tags and still have the issue.

Comment: You've commented out require. What's the reason? Were you getting errors? Change include back to require and update here with any errors you receive...

Comment: What error are you getting? Turn error reporting on so see what error it is giving

Comment: I commented out require hoping that include would work. Both have the same problem. I have changed it back, and still have the problem.

Comment: @Jay
Display php errors and tell us what error you are getting

Comment: Where exactly is the `<frame>` tag? Because it is not in your sample code

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and turn on error reporting. Place the following code at the beginning of `create.php` and let us know the error message(s) you receive.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('Test.php');

?>
```

My guess is that it is a path issue.

Comment: Okay... it works in IE 8, but not in my (admittedly overly-addon-filled) FF 5. grr...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need the `html` tags in your PHP-File. Second: you need to **execute** your function. Now you only defined it. Try

Test.php

```
<?php
function hello(){
    echo "hello";
}
hello();
?>
```

And make sure that both files are in the same directory.

Comment: the html tags have been removed: no solution there. Also note that create.php attempts to call the function "hello()" and fails. That is my problem.

Comment: This is what @Jay is currently doing, it's just in different files.

Comment: and they are in the same directory... right next to each other. The include works somewhat, because if I put the call to hello in Test.php, it will print. However, if the call is in create.php it will not print.

Answer (score 0):

use dirname(**FILE**) instead of a stright include

eg

if i have a dir

/var/www/html/include

and test.php resides in includes and your script is in html then use `dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/test.php`

if you need to go back in a dir the use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))`

depending on how many levels.

it also makes it dynamic so command line and browser will always fin the file

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below for create.php

```
<?php
require('Test.php');
?>
<html><body>
<?php 
hello(); 
echo 'does this work?';
?>
</body>
</html>
```